# Operators with subscripts, superscripts, and accents

Tags: math-operators

In mathematics, the tensor product between two vector spaces *U* and *V* is often notated

> *U* ⊗<sub>*K*</sub> *V*,

if the scalar field is called *K*. This is usually typed in TeX like `U\otimes_K V`. I wonder if this is the right way to type this? `\otimes` is usually a binary operator, but does TeX still see it this way when I add a *subscript*  to it? Should I perhaps write something like `U\mathbin{\otimes_K} V` instead?

MWE (even if I don't really see the point in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$U\otimes_K V$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the output of your MWE look like you expect?  Is the spacing any different with or without the subscript?

Comment: Yes, it does produce the output I expect; but that does not mean it is the *correct* way to do it, and problems can occasionally arise if it is done wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A math atom has three fields: the base, the subscript and the superscript. When you attach a subscript or superscript to a symbol, it doesn't lose its type. So the whole

```
\otimes_{K}
```

(the braces could be omitted here, because the subscript has just one token) is considered as a **Bin** atom. Thus with

```
U \otimes_{K} V
```

you get the sequence

> [*U*]<sub>Ord</sub> [medium space] [⊗*<sub>K</sub>*]<sub>Bin</sub>
>   [medium space] [*V*]<sub>Ord</sub>

(where brackets isolate atoms and spacings and the subscripts to `]` denote an atom's type).

You have only to pay attention to other cases: suppose you want to denote the tensor product of the right module *M<sub>A</sub>* with the left module *<sub>A</sub>N*. In this case

```
N_{A} \otimes {}_AM
```

should be used, because in

```
N_{A} \otimes _AM
```

the subscript would be interpreted as given to `\otimes`.

While I'm on it, I'll present a different situation. Suppose you need a “completed tensor product”. If you try

```
$U \hat{\otimes} V$
```

the spacing will be wrong. This is because `\hat{...}` builds an **Acc** atom (accent), which is then regarded as **Ord** when spaces are being added during the transformation of the math list into boxes. For this case `\mathbin` is necessary; of course it's better to define a command:

```
\newcommand{\ctens}{\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}}}
```

so that you can type

```
$U \ctens V$
```

or even

```
$U \ctens_{K} V$
```

and the subscript will be attached to the whole **Bin** atom resulting from `\ctens`.

### Full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ctens}{\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}}}

\begin{document}

$U\otimes_K V$ (good)

$U\mathbin{\otimes_K} V$ (the same)

$M_{A}\otimes {}_{A}N$ (good)

$M_{A}\otimes _{A}N$ (bad)

$U \hat{\otimes} V$ (bad)

$U \ctens V$ (good)

$U \ctens_{K} V$ (good)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: TeX help from an algebraist. Who could wish for more? `:-D`

Comment: @Gaussler I added some other bits that might be of interest if you are also into topology.

Comment: It's hard to do algebra without topology showing up all over the place, so yes, I am. I've learned to love topology, in fact. `:-)`

Comment: In fact, because your answer could be useful in greater generality than my original question, I have changed the title of the question. I might update the question itself if I feel less lazy.

Comment: Soon some analyst will come to discussion... lol

Comment: @Sigur That will have to be about the strong limit, `s-lim`. The lecture notes used at my university for functional analysis used `$s-\lim_{n\to\infty}$`. I'm still recovering from that.

Comment: P.S. personally, I would use `\widehat` in egreg's example; but that is a matter of taste.